# How to use bunyan logging for 3rd-party libraries?

Tags: logging, google-cloud-logging, bunyan

I'm using `bunyan` to send logs to Google Cloud Logger. Regular logs are not show up there. Or they do show up but as one-liners. If a regular `consonle.log` will be logging an object, then each property of this object will be displayed as a separated line, which is really hard to read.

The `bunyan` let me output only the title as the log for Google Cloud Logger and if I pass an object, then this object will be displayed as the log payload, which is good and easy to read.

I'm using a 3rd party npm package. It outputs it's own `console.log`s. How do I make bunyan to intercept those logs?

Comment: I have found this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/nodejs) about Setting Up Cloud Logging for Node.js, that might help you answer your questions.

Comment: this is exactly what I do. The problem is that 3rd party libs are not using this setup.

Comment: this [information](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan/wiki/Awesome-Bunyan) may be useful

Comment: @stkvtflw did you find a solution? Did you try monkey patching console.log?